# Access denied during PIC Programming in Windows XP

Tags: microcontroller

I'm programming a **PIC16F77** with **ProPic 2** which communicates via serial port. As I don't have this port in my PC, I used serial to USB adapter.
I'm using **ICProg** in **Windows 8**.

I've proggrammed it before but it was in Windows XP using the driver who specifies in http://www.ic-prog.com/index1.htm and worked perfectly.
But in this OS the only difference is the adapter, the program gives some errors while loading the driver:

> "Error occured (Access is denied) while loading the driver!"
>
> "Privileged instruction"

Comment: Maybe http://electronics.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 1):

If you're running this from command prompt, try this when launching command prompt: Right click. Run as administrator.

Then use as usual.

Answer (score 1):

Certain low-level instructions are forbidden to be used by the User under Windows: unfortunately, these 'privileged' instructions can include port control commands.
Details: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/112298/EN-US

" The inp(), outp(), and other I/O port related functions map to privileged processor instructions. For example, on Intel processors, the inp() and outp() functions end up calling the IN and OUT instructions. The privileged instruction exception occurs when these instructions are executed because typical Windows NT applications execute in a non privileged (user) mode. Only code executing in kernel mode has the necessary rights to execute privileged instructions."

Device drivers run in kernel mode: if you're getting this error on your program run, its trying to access on the low-level (which is kind of by definition what a port controller does)

Seeing as ic-prog.com's page on windows drivers was last changed on 06/09/08, which is not a good sign.